# Error while compiling project in mono that uses a GTK# lib

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

When i try to build my simple Mono GTK# project using command line

```
mcs  /pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0  Test.cs
```

compiler gives this error both on Linux and Windows:

> Package gtk-sharp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk-sharp.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'gtk-sharp' found
>   error CS8027: Error running pkg-config. Check the above output.

On Windows I tried to set full path to file gtk-sharp-2.0.pc, but that way pkg-config.exe crashes.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the windows environment variables, there should be a `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable. If there is no such variable, add it. If there is, check if the path is correct and has the gtk-sharp.pc file.

Comment: I have added this variable, but now pkg-config.exe crashes.